# Comparing between 2 slopes, each represents the change in a different group

Tags: regression, time-series

I am looking at proportion of two kinds of T cells cells within a population of many T cells. Now, I can see that there is a difference between the two groups in proliferation between one time point and the next one (e.g. if group 1 accounts for 1% of the cells before on day 0, and group 2 accounts for 2%, on day 3, after some treatment, each group accounts for 5% of the cells - so on day 3 there's no difference between the groups, but the slope between days 0 and 3 is 2-times steeper for group 2 compared with group 1) - which statistical test should I use to determine if the differences between the slopes are significant? Using "Prism", can I do that using the "are the slopes equal" option within linear regression (using whatever arbitrary numbers I'd want to for the X axis, which it forces me to fill in)?